# click(jquery) executes the function as soon as script is loaded and doesn't responds to clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to execute a function using `.click` (jquery 3.4.1) when a button is pressed but the function executes as soon as the page loads. And after some trying I thought there might be some piece of code that is making it behave this way so I created new files with basic elements and tried using it but it still didn't work. I thought I might be doing something wrong and so I checked a tutorial but it didn't help because I was doing the same thing.
I tried `.on('click', function)` too but the result was same.

The .html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Some Text</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The .js file

```
$('h1').click(console.log('Clicked'))
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: `$('h1').click(console.log('Clicked'))` <-- executes the console and what it returns is assigned to the event listener. So that is why it is not working. You basically just did. `$('h1').click(undefined)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attaching a click event listener to the h1

```
$('h1').click(console.log('Clicked'))
```

What is does is it executes the console and what it returns is assigned to the event listener. So that is why it is not working. You basically just did the following because console does not return anything.

```
$('h1').click(undefined)
```

so you have to assign it a function

```
$('h1').click(function () { console.log('Clicked') })
```

---

```js
// Your original way written out to see what is happening
// $('h1').click(console.log('Clicked')) // code below is same thing as this line 
var cl = console.log("Clicked Original Way") // will log message
console.log('cl is:', cl) // cl is: undefined
$('h1').click(cl) // aka $('h1').click(undefined)

// solution 1
$('h1').click(function() {
  console.log('Clicked')
})

// solution 2
function myClickFunction() {
  console.log('Clicked w/ function')
}
$('h1').click(myClickFunction)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Some Text</h1>
```

Comment: Okay so even if i change it to a function it didn't do anything. The behaviour was the same. This is a simplified version where I did not define a function because of simplicity. I got the answer though. So thanks for helping.

Comment: Well if it still did not do anything then you have an issue with code we do not see in your simple example.

Comment: Okay, I get what you meant by using console.log directly. Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: You can use a function reference in the click (updated the code above), but you are not using a function reference. In your code you are saying execute this method and whatever it returns, assigned to the event listener. Since console.log returns undefined, it assigns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument you're passing in is not a callable function, jQuery is unable to call it when the click actually happens. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm in the first go. When i used `.on('click', function)` it did the same thing. But for some reason doing it this way does the job. Why so? Why can't I just straight up do this `$('h1').on('click', function)` ?

Comment: Look at the difference between the code. `.on('click'...` is saying "on a click event, do this..." and `.click()` is saying "trigger a click now." So theoretically executing a `.click()` would make the `.on('click'` event fire.

Comment: Okay so my question was why can't I use `$('h1').on('click', function)` directly instead of what you suggested.

Comment: @JoshToth Um, what are you talking about with `click(foobar)`? It does not execute a click when it has an argument passed in. That is very misleading. `click` without any arguments does trigger the event listeners. `click` with arguments is just another way of calling on(). So your description text is misleading since it is NOT triggering a click.

Comment: @epascarello my bad, haven't had coffee yet. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

`click` expects a function

```
$('h1').click(function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

The way you are doing it, is to output `'Clicked'` and have a `undefined` handler "sent" to `click()`.

Check out the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Yes, Okay I see the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It is actually undefined and not null.

Comment: you are right epascarello, `console.log` does not have an return value. I changed the answer accordingly